# GIT multiple local checkouts

Tags: git, version-control, repository, git-checkout

I want to checkout multiple branches of the same git repostiory on the same Computer (Linux and Windows). However as the repository might be huge, I would prefer to have the repository once and only multiple working directories.

Is this possible?
How so?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is possible since Git 2.5 and its `git worktree` command.

It replaces an older script `contrib/workdir/git-new-workdir`, with a more robust mechanism where those "linked" working trees are actually recorded in the main repo new `$GIT_DIR/worktrees` folder (so that work on any OS, including Windows).

Once you have cloned a repo (in a folder like `/path/to/myrepo`), you can add worktrees for different branches in *different* independent paths (`/path/to/br1`, `/path/to/br2`), while having those working trees linked to the main repo history (no need to use a `--git-dir` option anymore)

See "[Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)"