# Local push repo for 100% uptime of script

Tags: git, git-workflow

I looked through similar questions and couldn't find a suitable answer.

I have a script that needs to be available for daily reports. Is it possible to host my code in a separate directory/ repo and only 'push' major updates to this directory/ repo for maximum uptime?

Right now, I'm working in the directory the script is hosted in, so the script is broken from the time I checkout a dev branch, until I return to master.

---

For example, I want leave the working file in one directory that gets major updates only:

```
/daily_report/daily_report.sh
```

And then have another directory for incremental development that allows the main directory to be unchanged until a new major update is ready to go live:

```
/daily_report_dev/daily_report.sh
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider a checkout of your repo twice: two different branches in two different folders.

- one branch checked out in `/daily_report`
- one branch checked out in `/daily_report_dev`

[Since Git 2.5, you can checkout a repo in multiple folders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32043748/6309).

That way, you can work in the `/daily_report_dev` folder (checked out to the `dev` branch), without impacting your main branch, checked out in the `/daily_report` folder.