# Can I have different git branch in different ubuntu terminals or workspaces?

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-branch

I use Ubuntu with workspaces enabled. While my code compiles in a branch, I would like to do some work on another branch. But branch changes go seem to be global across terminals and workspaces.

Is it possible to set a different git branch for one terminal or workspace without affecting the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in the same copy of the repository. The way git works, the current state is a function of things stored in a .git folder at the top level of your repository. It doesn't have anything to do with any individual application using git. However, you can accomplish something pretty close as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32043533/git-multiple-local-checkouts#32043748).